# NavigationDrawer with "special" listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, navigation-drawer

currently I am using a standard NavigationDrawer which uses a listview to display the items.

There's one issue though: The last two items in this listview need to be at the bottom of the screen, while the others are on top. It should look something like this:

|item 1|

|item 2|

|item 3|

|item 4|

|item 5|

-space-

-space-

-space-

|item 6|

|item 7|

I was thinking about 2 listviews, but then there would be a problem with small screens and scrolling. Then I was thinking about not using a listview but putting each item in there individually (maybe using a LinearLayotu within a ScrollView), not sure if that's the best way though.

Is there an elegant way to accomplish this?

Comment: you can add the item 6 and 7 as footer to listview so they will be always at the bottom

Comment: `ListView` isn't well suited to this. Just use a `ScrollView`. No need to worry about recycling views for 7 items.

Comment: Did it resolved? *or* Should I delete my answer?

Answer (score 0):

ListView would be the good option

Try this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    selectItem(position);
                }
            });
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar()
            .getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1, new String[] {
                    getString(R.string.title_section1),
                    getString(R.string.title_section2),
                    getString(R.string.title_section3),
                    getString(R.string.title_section4),
                    getString(R.string.title_section5),
                    getString(R.string.title_section6),
                    getString(R.string.title_section7), 
                    getString(R.string.title_section8), 
                    getString(R.string.title_section9), 
                    getString(R.string.title_section10),
                    getString(R.string.title_section11),
                    getString(R.string.title_section12),
                    getString(R.string.title_section13),
                    getString(R.string.title_section14),
    }));

    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    return mDrawerListView;
}
```

activity_main XML:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.example.demoapp.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

---

fragment_navigation_drawer.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="232dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    tools:context="com.example.demoapp.NavigationDrawerFragment" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Button" />
```

image :

[image]

[image]

Comment: But this looks what I already have, or am I not seeing something?

Comment: Thank you, could you post a picture of how it would look like?

Answer (score 0):

Add a LinearLayout inside a ScrollView and use Buttons. Don´t use a list footer, in a small device items 1-5 will scroll and items 6-7 will be fixed.

You can use styles to change buttons appearance.